# How to unwrap/unravel the curved face of a cylinder to become a rectangle

Tags: animation, objects, transforms, video, geometry

Just to give a bit of background; I generally create 2D animations using Apple Motion on videos, but I'm looking to do a small number of 3D animations.

I have no prior experience with 3D animations, but I've come across Blender before.

I'm just wondering whether blender can create video animations for the folllowing:

- shade sides to a shape, such as a cuboid
- general animation of a 3D shape (rotate it around so that others can see the other faces)
- animate the increase the size/dimensions/lengths of a 3D shape
- **animate the unwrapping/unraveling of a cylinder (in particular unravel the curved face to become a rectangle)**

I assume that the first three are easily done, but the fourth could be more difficult.

I work as a maths teacher so I'm showing my students some animations of 3D shapes on how to find surface area/volume etc in a fun way.

Assuming that Blender can do this, I can then get cracking learning Blender ASAP to complete these tasks.

Thanks,

Steve90

Comment: yes it can do that tasks

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. 
Are these easily done for someone who has no prior experience?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, that's appreciated :)
I work as a maths teacher so I'm showing my students some animations of 3D shapes on how to find surface area/volume etc in a fun way. I've been makign 2D animations in my classes already: just looking to do a smaller number of 3D ones.

Comment: @Steve90 Ahh, okay. Well, it doesn’t have to be too pretty then, just make sense. I’ll toy around a bit. Meanwhile, here's the Blender Manual page on animating (introduction): https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/introduction.html

Comment: Yes exactly. Great, I'm sure with practice I can make the animations look good. I'll start learning the software tomorrow 

Comment: I recommend you "fake" the cylinder unrolling using gradients in the shaders to have the side of the cylinder disappear as the rolled out version appears, or use a cloth simulation.

Comment: Great, I'll look into that. Thanks again. If I have any trouble with that, I'll look on the forum once I become more acquainted with the software.

Comment: Hello and welcome. This [BSE is a question and answer site](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) and it works a bit different than a common forum. I would edit and focus this question more to your 4th point so it will be helpful for other users with a similar problem in future.

Comment: "Are these easily done for someone who has no prior experience?"  You're a math teacher.  Is trigonometry easy to do for someone who has no prior experience?  Yes, it's easy, after learning what you need to get there; it's part of secondary school curriculum, after all, and all of those students started with no math experience.  How long will it take to get there?  Just like your students, it depends.  Some will get there more quickly than others.  Some could be learning trig in fifth grade, and some will only ever be able to learn it, even assuming hard work, in college.